# Swift - Pod Install Framework

Tags: ios, mobile, swift

Senhores, boa tarde!

Onde trabalho, estamos prestando suporte para um cliente que tem um app iOS que utiliza diversos frameworks.

Abriram um chamado de um erro, fomos analisar e o erro está acontecendo por conta de um endpoint que está errado.

O problema é que esse endpoint está em um framework desenvolvido por eles mesmos, framework esse que faz a chamada de qualquer endpoint.

Minha dúvida é a seguinte, como fazer pare refletir a alteração desse framework no projeto? Visto que o framework não tem um "podfile".

Comment: Os links dos endpoints deverias estar em um arquivo de configuração, acho q não tem muita opção além de pedir para eles os novos arquivos ou ainda pedir um fw modificado com os endpoints em arquivos.

Answer (score 0):

Daniel, se o framework mencionado foi desenvolvido por seu cliente, é necessário atualizar o mesmo para que passe a funcionar com os novos endpoints.

Se o projeto no qual o framework está sendo utilizado não tem nenhum gerenciador de dependências configurado (como *CocoaPods*, ou *Carthage*), provavelmente será necessário atualizar o framework manualmente. Isto é, copiar o arquivo binário compilado pelo projeto do framework para a estrutura do projeto do aplicativo em questão.

Comment: Olá, era isso mesmo.
Alteramos o framework mas não estava fazendo o build.
Dai descobrimos que no xCode era necessário habilitar uma opção para que fizesse o build do framework junto com o build do projeto.